# How to automatically delete the original files after encrypting with GPG?

Tags: linux, command-line, security, encryption, gnupg

I need to use GPG on a folder with a lot of files and subfolders. I can use "find" + "gpg" for that and I can encrypt all the files but my issue is GPG does not delete the original file after successful encryption.

What is the best and the most secure way to delete the original file(s) after GPG does it encryption properly? I do not want to delete my files prematurely and I do not want remove unencrypted files (due to error, permission etc issues with GPG operation) improperly.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`shred`** sounds like your weapon of choice, for securely deleting files, but see below for filesystem limitations.

And if you're using the terminal, some bash/sh scripting might be useful. If you want to use an error-checking one line? Like this to move a file if it's encrypted correctly, and print a message if it wasn't?

```
gpg --encrypt <options> "$file" && mv "$file" todel-folder || echo "Error, $file did not encrypt"
```

Or you could put together some multi-line "if success" & "if fail" items for logging, using some curly brackets:

```
gpg --encrypt <options> "$file" && {
  echo "gpg on $file successful" >> logfile
  mv "$file" todel-folder
  } || {
  echo "Error, $file did not encrypt" >> logfile
}
```

And then after, you can securely delete/wipe/`shred` the files in `todel-folder`, or just shred them immediately instead of using `mv`:

```
gpg --encrypt <options> "$file" && {
    echo "gpg on $file successful" >> logfile
    shred "$file" && { 
        echo "shred on $file successful" >> logfile
        } ||  {
        echo "shred on $file successful" >> logfile
        }
    } || {
    echo "Error, $file did not encrypt" >> logfile
}
```

See `man shred` for some options and warnings:

```
shred - overwrite a file to hide its contents, and optionally delete it
```

> CAUTION: Note that shred relies on a very  important  assumption: 
>   that    the  file system overwrites data in place.  This is the
>   traditional way    to do things, but many modern file system designs
>   do not  satisfy  this    assumption.   The following are examples of
>   file systems on which shred    is not effective, or is not guaranteed
>   to be effective in all file system modes:
>
> - log-structured or journaled file systems, such as those supplied
>     with    AIX and Solaris (and JFS, ReiserFS, XFS, Ext3, etc.)
> - file systems that write redundant data and  carry  on  even  if 
>     some    writes fail, such as RAID-based file systems
> - file  systems  that  make snapshots, such as Network Appliance's
>     NFS    server
> - file systems that cache in temporary locations, such as NFS
>     version 3    clients
> - compressed file systems
>
> In  the  case  of  ext3 file systems, the above disclaimer applies
>   (and    shred is thus of limited  effectiveness)  only  in 
>   data=journal  mode,    which  journals  file  data  in addition to
>   just metadata.  In both the    data=ordered (default) and
>   data=writeback modes, shred works as  usual.    Ext3  journaling 
>   modes  can  be  changed  by adding the data=something    option to the
>   mount  options  for  a  particular  file  system  in  the
>   /etc/fstab file, as documented in the mount man page (man mount).

Comment: well the thing is that I do not want to move files around because it can get very complicated if something goes wrong, like restructuring it back in the case of a problem. No ?

Comment: The move there is only executed if gpg was successful, and as a precaution before the irreversible shred. But you could do `shred` instead of `mv` and get it gone right then? I'll add some possibly useful multi-line stuff for logging