# Encyrpting a file with gpg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, gnupg

I was following the advice on this site: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-easily-encryptdecrypt-a-file-in-linux-with-gpg/

I ran this command: gpg -c test.txt.

But then it created a separate file called test.txt.gpg and it left the original file. I want to encrypt a certain file so that it can't be accessed with a live CD. How can I password protect the original file?

I am using ubuntu and don't want to download a special program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically delete the original files after encrypting with GPG?](http://superuser.com/questions/879188/how-to-automatically-delete-the-original-files-after-encrypting-with-gpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's how symmetric encryption with gpg works. You can use the `-o` option to specify an output. If you want to delete the source file, after successful encryption, you can use something like this:

```
gpg -c file && rm -rf file
```

This way you will have encrypted file only. Also, have a look at the `shred` command, it's quite handy when it comes to deleting sensitive data.

```
gpg -c file && shred -u file
```

Comment: Good idea. So something like this would work well?  gpg -c [file name] && shred [file name]

Comment: yes, but please test first on non-important files. Also, use shred with `-u`, as it will 1st overwrite the file contents, and then delete it. If you don't use `-u` it will only overwrite the file.